# Braintree API: How can I tell which payment_method is associated with my nonce?

Tags: payment, braintree, payment-method

Background:

1. I create a braintree customer with firstName, lastName and email
2. I use the dropin ui in checkout form and it creates a payment_method and token and sends me a nonce. Good so far.
3. I need to add a billing address to the payment_method before I charge the nonce...

Question:
How can I discover which payment_method is associated with my nonce?

Edit to add:
There is a paradoxical reference at the bottom of the [javascript+PHP](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/reference/request/payment-method/update) page to an otherwise undocumented [paymentMethodNonce] parameter which uses an also undocumented [options][verifyCard] parameter. I suppose I could run [paymentMethodNonce] sans [options] against each payment_method token associated the user and inspect the errors... lol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, I suggest you [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

When you use the Drop-In UI, it doesn't automatically create a payment method, just a nonce. You pass the nonce back to your server and [create a payment method](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/reference/request/payment-method/create) with it:

```
$result = Braintree_PaymentMethod::create(array(
    'customerId' => '12345',
    'paymentMethodNonce' => 'nonce-from-the-client'
));
```

If the nonce points to an already-vaulted payment method for that customer, you'll get back the existing payment method rather than a duplicate.

You can then update that payment method to add a billing address before using it to create a transaction.

Comment: from we can able to find customerId? And once we get Result<PaymentMethod> then how to use them to send nonce value to server? As my server wants nonce value from client side and I am able to find that by using Braintree.PaymentMethodNonceListener (). But in response it is showing that "Cannot determine payment method.". Please suggest me the right path.

Comment: Well, when I use the dropin it *does* create a payment method, however, you are right. If I attempt to create a payment_method with the nonce, it does return the existing payment method created with that nonce. Thanks!

Comment: @anddev I suggest you [contact the Braintree support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).

Comment: I don't see the "find or create" functionality of `create()` [in the docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create/php) or in practice using sandbox cards.

Comment: @jchook It's not find or create. When I say "an already-vaulted payment method" I don't mean the credit card number matches an already vaulted one, I mean that the nonce was created from the ID of a vaulted payment method.